# How to authenticate our users in our website with Google Account

Tags: php, api, authentication

How to authenticate a user using google account in our website. i want a user to be redirect to google login page and then redirect him to my website. I want this implementation in PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Authentication can be done using OpenID. A detailed document is there in Google http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OpenID.html

Update: The links have been deprecated by Google. Refer to the following links to use Google's own [OAuth2 API documentation](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2) instead of bothering so much into reading the libraries because they are very complicated and may end up losing focus.

Answer (score 4):

You want [OAuth](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth.html).

[oauth-php](http://code.google.com/p/oauth-php/) is a library to help with this in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Google Data API can help you to achieve this.

Go to: http://code.google.com/apis/base/client-download.html

and grab the php apis. you will get samples over there as well

I hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

the documentation at google kinsda looks  to much to read to understand you can also consider the following blogs .in my opinion i think they have simplifed the explanation

1. [w3lessons](http://www.w3lessons.com/2011/10/introduction-to-website-login-with.html)
2. [9lessons](http://www.9lessons.info/2011/07/login-with-google-account.html)
3. [jobby joseph](http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/php-sdk-3-0-graph-api-base-facebook-connect-tutorial/)

hope you read through this blogs ,am sure you'll get the insight you are looking for