# How to post with Google Plus API - Java

Tags: java, api, google-plus

I'm trying to create a web service to use the Google Plus API. I'm writing it in java, however I can't figure out what files I need and how I would go about posting to Google plus groups using Java

If you have any insite please could you post relavent links and helpful tips to help me out.

**EDIT 1:**

I have been playing around with the GooglePlus API provived by Google and have written a project based on the sample code given from this page: https://developers.google.com/+/domains/posts/creating

The code runs fine until it gets to the `GoogleTokenResponse tokenResponse = flow.newTokenRequest(code).setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URI).execute();` line. Where it returns a null error. I am copying the link provided in the console and pasting in the code, however everytime it just returned a null error, is there a specific part of the returned code given that causes an issue?

Comment: I assume that line actually comes from the sample code on https://developers.google.com/+/domains/authentication/ correct? Please clarify the question, particularly since the code on that page talks about a command line, while you specified you're doing it as part of a web service.

Comment: You should also clarify that you're trying to do this as part of a Google Apps Domain and not for normal Google accounts. The Domain API is for use by Apps Domains only.

Comment: Currently I'm trying to get the mechanism working using the sample code, so command line for the moment, however will be migrating once that works, and yes the line comes from the authentication sample code

Comment: @Prisoner What do you mean with by saying `You should also clarify that you're trying to do this as part of a Google Apps Domain and not for normal Google accounts. The Domain API is for use by Apps Domains only.`

Comment: Are you logging in using a Google Apps Domain account, or are you logging in with a GMail account?

Comment: I'm not sure, I'm testing with my Uni email address - I assume they use Google Apps as there is additional stuff, but for the most part its just a Gmail account - I get the sense I can't log in with just a GMail account from what you've been saying, how would I go about writing this to work with a standard Gmail account

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64495/discussion-between-zach-ross-clyne-and-prisoner).

Answer (score 1):

Posting to Google+ is only supported for accounts in a Google Apps Domain (and even then, with restrictions).

If you are logging in using a GMail account - you don't have an Apps Domain account. If you're logging in using some other email address (ie - you have an email address, but you can't use Google account features such as GMail or Google Drive with it) then you don't have an Apps Domain account. If you are using a Domain account, your Domain admin may need to enable Google+ for your Domain before this works.

See https://developers.google.com/+/domains/getting-started for the differences between what you can do with the Domains API and the regular Plus API.

Note that neither API lets you post to a Google+ Community or post publicly. The Domains API *does* let you post to a user's circle, as long as the members of that circle are also part of the Domain. The Domain API also lets you post to everyone in the Domain. The normal Plus API does not allow posting at all.

There is a third API, knows as the Pages API, which allows Pages to publicly post on their stream. This API, however, is available to a limited number of partners such as Hootsuite. You can read more at https://developers.google.com/+/api/pages-signup, but there isn't much more available publicly.

Comment: I am now using a Google Apps Domain account and it still comes back with the same error in the same place, am I supposed to have some sort of configuration somewhere which I'm missing?

Comment: Make sure the Domain is permitted to use Google+ and the account is a Google+ enabled account (ie - it has a Google+ profile and you can post to Google+ with it normally).

Comment: All of which are true and still nothing... However just been discussing the actual aim for this and what we are after is for the user to be able to post to a page - Which I know is possible to do (see Hootsuite), is there a different API that is needed to be used in order to post to a page?

Comment: The [Pages API](https://developers.google.com/+/api/pages-signup) is limited to partners only.

Comment: I've updated to add more information about posting to a page - but as @abraham noted, this isn't publicly available.

Answer (score 0):

Your web service should first authenticate against Google. This authentication can either be using a service account (if you want to post only through one account) or users's account (if you want to post via user's account) using oAuth mechanism.

For more details about how to authenticate, refer to [How to authenticate our users in our website with Google Account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4201984/how-to-authenticate-our-users-in-our-website-with-google-account)

Have a look at https://developers.google.com/+/api/ for detailed information about how Google Plus APIs can be used.

Comment: What requirements does my project need in order to work becuase I've got an existing project which already posts to Facebook LinkedIn and Twitter, and I would like to add functionality to post to Google+ as well. For the moment, I will only be posting through 1 account to groups associated with that account, however, I've looked for hours at the google api you've provided and I've setup a project in the Google developers console, however when running the Servlet that is demonstrated in the example doesn't seem to work

Comment: Also, is there a way to hard code authentication given that I will only be using the one account

Comment: To answer your second question - Yes, you can create a service account and download the P12 key. This needs to be done from Google console. Once you use the certificate from this service account, it is like hardcoding the authentication for calling Google Plus API.

Comment: So I wouldn't be able to do it with Database stored credentials for example?

Comment: P12 cert file comes with service account is nothing but credential.  If you are looking for username and password, I think Google does not allow API authentication using username and password. I am not quite sure though.

Comment: So I could store the P12 cert in a BLOB on the database for authentication and pull it in from within my Java with a SQL query

Comment: Please could you look over the edit I have made, as I have made some progress but still need help with how to post

Comment: If you are using it in single web application, you can put it in classpath and read it using context class loader.

Google's authenticate API accepts it as java.io.File argument.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into that when I get this bit working - Could you let me know your thoughts on my edit please

Comment: Can you add the error stack for null error you said? Also are you getting error while authenticating or authentication is successful but you are getting error while calling plus API?